# Flask: Trigger AJAX call on POST request

Tags: javascript, ajax, flask

I have this flask app, where a JSON request is POSTed to route("/webhook") and stored in database. I have another route and page to display the content of the database, and needs to be updated( possibly with AJAX) after a POST on the "/webhook". How do I trigger the AJAX call when there is a POST to "/webhook", so that it updates my display page on route("/").

`app.py`

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'blah blah blah'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = "sqlite:///site.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=False, nullable=True)
    userinfo = db.Column(db.Text, unique=False, nullable=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<User: {self.id}"

@app.route('/webhook',methods=['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = request.get_json()
    new_user = User(username=data['username'], userinfo=data['userinfo'])
    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify({'username':new_user.username, 'userinfo':new_user.userinfo})


@app.route('/', methods=['GET','POST'])
def display():
    users = User.query.all()
    return render_template('show.html',users=users)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

`show.html`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Displayer</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3>Users</h3>
    <button id="refresh">Refresh</button>
    <ul>
        {% for user in users %}
        <li>
            {{ user.username }}
        </li>
        <span> {{ user.userinfo }}</span>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>

    <span id='new_user'></span>
</body>
</html>
```

What should be my AJAX call and how do update the display page to load all content in my database.

Comment: I am posting with [POSTman](https://www.postman.com/). the POST data comes from outside api webhook

Comment: there is no `/show`?

Comment: @appleapple sorry. "/" is my display page. Edited

Comment: anyway, simply use ajax to fetch data (from `/webhook`) and update the page?

Comment: @appleapple I wanted to update the content from database when the POST request occurs. There should be some way to trigger the AJAX whenever POST request occurs

Comment: @AvenDesta then you need to use something like Websockets or Server Send Event.

Comment: for some cases, simply periodically fetch data / long pull is well enough.

Comment: in which html file do you want the ajax to be in? add that html file to your question.

Comment: @appleapple thanks. already did that (polling) and it works, though I think there should be a better way. Can I implement sockets here? I mean the API server is only doing POST, and will not change its protocol to WB.

Comment: @AvenDesta you just need to change the fetch url (e.g. `/getupdate`) (not page url `/`) to establise a websocket / SSE connection. and send notify to them when `/webhook` occurs. no need to change `/webhook`'s protocol.

Comment: @appleapple ok, I'll try it